# Runtime error: CUDA out of memory: Cant train SEGAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am currently trying to run a SEGAN for speech enhancement but can't seem to get the network to start training since it runs the following error:

**Runtime error: CUDA out of memory: Tried to allocate 30.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.00 GiB total capacity; 2.00 GiB already allocated; 5.91 MiB free; 2.03 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch**

I have already tried to include torch.cuda.empty_cache() but that did not seem to have solved the issue

This is the script I am currently running

```
import argparse
import os

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from scipy.io import wavfile
from torch import optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm

from data_preprocess import sample_rate
from model import Generator, Discriminator
from utils import AudioDataset, emphasis

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Train Audio Enhancement')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=50, type=int, help='train batch size')
    parser.add_argument('--num_epochs', default=86, type=int, help='train epochs number')

    opt = parser.parse_args()
    BATCH_SIZE = opt.batch_size
    NUM_EPOCHS = opt.num_epochs

    # load data
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    print('loading data...')
    train_dataset = AudioDataset(data_type='train')
    test_dataset = AudioDataset(data_type='test')
    train_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    test_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
    # generate reference batch
    ref_batch = train_dataset.reference_batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    # create D and G instances
    discriminator = Discriminator()
    generator = Generator()
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        discriminator.cuda()
        generator.cuda()
        ref_batch = ref_batch.cuda()
    ref_batch = Variable(ref_batch)
    print("# generator parameters:", sum(param.numel() for param in generator.parameters()))
    print("# discriminator parameters:", sum(param.numel() for param in discriminator.parameters()))
    # optimizers
    g_optimizer = optim.RMSprop(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    d_optimizer = optim.RMSprop(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0001)


    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        train_bar = tqdm(train_data_loader)
        for train_batch, train_clean, train_noisy in train_bar:

            # latent vector - normal distribution
            z = nn.init.normal(torch.Tensor(train_batch.size(0), 1024, 8))
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                train_batch, train_clean, train_noisy = train_batch.cuda(), train_clean.cuda(), train_noisy.cuda()
                z = z.cuda()
            train_batch, train_clean, train_noisy = Variable(train_batch), Variable(train_clean), Variable(train_noisy)
            z = Variable(z)

            # TRAIN D to recognize clean audio as clean
            # training batch pass
            discriminator.zero_grad()
            outputs = discriminator(train_batch, ref_batch)
            clean_loss = torch.mean((outputs - 1.0) ** 2)  # L2 loss - we want them all to be 1
            clean_loss.backward()

            # TRAIN D to recognize generated audio as noisy
            generated_outputs = generator(train_noisy, z)
            outputs = discriminator(torch.cat((generated_outputs, train_noisy), dim=1), ref_batch)
            noisy_loss = torch.mean(outputs ** 2)  # L2 loss - we want them all to be 0
            noisy_loss.backward()

            # d_loss = clean_loss + noisy_loss
            d_optimizer.step()  # update parameters

            # TRAIN G so that D recognizes G(z) as real
            generator.zero_grad()
            generated_outputs = generator(train_noisy, z)
            gen_noise_pair = torch.cat((generated_outputs, train_noisy), dim=1)
            outputs = discriminator(gen_noise_pair, ref_batch)

            g_loss_ = 0.5 * torch.mean((outputs - 1.0) ** 2)
            # L1 loss between generated output and clean sample
            l1_dist = torch.abs(torch.add(generated_outputs, torch.neg(train_clean)))
            g_cond_loss = 100 * torch.mean(l1_dist)  # conditional loss
            g_loss = g_loss_ + g_cond_loss

            # backprop + optimize
            g_loss.backward()
            g_optimizer.step()

            train_bar.set_description(
                'Epoch {}: d_clean_loss {:.4f}, d_noisy_loss {:.4f}, g_loss {:.4f}, g_conditional_loss {:.4f}'
                    .format(epoch + 1, clean_loss.data[0], noisy_loss.data[0], g_loss.data[0], g_cond_loss.data[0]))

        # TEST model
        test_bar = tqdm(test_data_loader, desc='Test model and save generated audios')
        for test_file_names, test_noisy in test_bar:
            z = nn.init.normal(torch.Tensor(test_noisy.size(0), 1024, 8))
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                test_noisy, z = test_noisy.cuda(), z.cuda()
            test_noisy, z = Variable(test_noisy), Variable(z)
            fake_speech = generator(test_noisy, z).data.cpu().numpy()  # convert to numpy array
            fake_speech = emphasis(fake_speech, emph_coeff=0.95, pre=False)

            for idx in range(fake_speech.shape[0]):
                generated_sample = fake_speech[idx]
                file_name = os.path.join('results',
                                         '{}_e{}.wav'.format(test_file_names[idx].replace('.npy', ''), epoch + 1))
                wavfile.write(file_name, sample_rate, generated_sample.T)

        # save the model parameters for each epoch
        g_path = os.path.join('epochs', 'generator-{}.pkl'.format(epoch + 1))
        d_path = os.path.join('epochs', 'discriminator-{}.pkl'.format(epoch + 1))
        torch.save(generator.state_dict(), g_path)
        torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), d_path)
```

Comment: You should probably lower the batch size for starter.

Answer (score 1):

Try to lower your batch size (like David S mentionned). Also run the test without gradient computation using `with torch.no_grad():` statement. If you wish to run your training with a bigger batch and you have insufficient memory one solution is to use gradient accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a few things:

- lower batch size (as previously mentioned)
- for inference use `with torch.no_grad()` which saves CUDA memory by not keeping gradient in memory
- Use automated mixed precision

### Automated mixed precision

You need PyTorch layers (`1.6.0`) to do it easily. Check [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/amp_examples.html).

Where feasible (e.g. `torch.nn.Conv2d`), parameters will be casted to `float16`, which speeds up training and requires less memory (in some cases, layers like `BatchNorm` will be kept as `float32` due to running mean).

In your discriminator and generator case, check section [Working with Multiple Models, Losses, and Optimizers](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/amp_examples.html#working-with-multiple-models-losses-and-optimizers).

Example code for multiple models (refer to docs for more info and how it works exactly):

```
scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()

for epoch in epochs:
    for input, target in data:
        optimizer0.zero_grad()
        optimizer1.zero_grad()
        with autocast():
            output0 = model0(input)
            output1 = model1(input)
            loss0 = loss_fn(2 * output0 + 3 * output1, target)
            loss1 = loss_fn(3 * output0 - 5 * output1, target)

        scaler.scale(loss0).backward(retain_graph=True)
        scaler.scale(loss1).backward()

        # You can choose which optimizers receive explicit unscaling, if you
        # want to inspect or modify the gradients of the params they own.
        scaler.unscale_(optimizer0)

        scaler.step(optimizer0)
        scaler.step(optimizer1)

        scaler.update()
```

(main point is to perform single `scaler` update).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to reduce the batchsize, that didn't solve the problem. How do I implement with torch.no_grad() in my code?